# ng build generate a blank index.html and ng build --prod giving me error unknown argument prod

Tags: angular, angular14

**The following errors shown in blank index console**
[image]

**files generated by `ng build`**
[image]

Comment: `ng build --prod` has been deprecated and removed with Angular v14. Use `ng build --configuration production` instead. See the available options for `ng build` [here](https://angular.io/cli/build).

Comment: after this i got same empty index.html. How can i see that my app is working or not ? it is working fine in ng serve.

Answer (score 1):

ng build --prod is deprecated since Angular 15

use

`ng build --configuration production`

and

`ng build --configuration development`

as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Are these two problems related? Please provide some more info about your problem.

The new way to use `ng build` is `ng build --configuration` [environmentName]

Comment: after this command i got same error still my index.html is empty

Comment: does `ng serve` work properly?